# new ArrayList<Set<?>>() - Why is it OK?

Tags: java, generics

If

```
    new ArrayList<?>();  // is not Legal
```

And if

```
    new ArrayList<? extends Number>();   // is not Legal,
```

Then why is

```
    new ArrayList<Set<?>>();    // IS Legal
```

Can someone explain with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because in your concrete type declaration you're using interface as generic parameter. Think about how it would be used in the future:

```
List someList = new ArrayList<Set<?>>();    
Set<?> someSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
someList.add(someSet);
```

In first line - you're defining a list of `ArrayList` type, that will be holding 'some set' (of any type). Then, in second line you're declaring and defining set of concrete type `HashSet`. It is casted into `Set<?>` so there is no problem with adding it to previously created list.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the ArrayList you must specify an explicit type to its generic parameter. `?` or `? extends Number` are not types. `Set<?>` is a type (namely a Set, where we don't care about its generic type).

Answer (score 1):

The answers have been given already, so here's what you would need to do *instead*:

First of what if you don't care about the type of things the list contains:

```
ArrayList example1 = new ArrayList(); // any object will do.
ArrayList<Object> example2 = new ArrayList<Object>(); // since everything inherits from Object anyway...
```

Then what if you want to add arbitrary `Number` objects:

```
ArrayList<Number> example3 = new ArrayList<Number>(); // any Number may be added
```

Lastly, previous answers gloss over the meaning of your last example.

```
ArrayList<Set<?>> example4 = new ArrayList<Set<?>>();
```

That one means you construct an `ArrayList` in which you expect to find/put `Set`s which may contain objects of arbitrary type. I.e. you don't care about what is in the `Set`, but you do care that it is `Set`s you add to your `ArrayList`.

As a result, *within the scope of all operations performed on your newly declared/created `ArrayList`* the part of `Set<?>` can be freely translated to `Set`: the result program will have equivalent semantics.

Answer (score 0):

That's because *unknown* `?` cannot be translated to any type.

```
new ArrayList<?>();
```

will result in the following (assuming this could compile).

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>();
list.add(? e); //Java sees this as WTF???
```

Since this `?` is unknown, java translates this to `list.add(null e);` and this is errornous.

Comment: If that were true, `List<?> list = new ArrayList<Object>()` should also be illegal, but it's not.

Comment: @yshavit, I didn't specify `ArrayList<Object>()` but `ArrayList<?>()`, what you specified is another different case.

Comment: I understand, but if you replace your line `List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>()` with `List<?> list = new ArrayList<Object>()`, your second line would be completely unchanged. So that doesn't explain why `new ArrayList<?>()` isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`new ArrayList<?>()` wouldn't be very useful. It's helpful to think about what the wildcards mean:

- `? extends Foo` means you can't put anything in (except `null`), but you can get objects out as `Foo`
- `? super Foo` means you can put `Foo`s in, but you can't get objects out (except as `Object`)
- `?` is the intersection: you can't put anything in (except `null`), and you can't get objects out (except as `Object`)

Note that `List<Foo>` can be cast to `List<? extends Foo>`, `List<? super Foo>` or `List<?>`, but none of those three can be safely cast to `List<Foo>`.

So, let's say you created a `new ArrayList<?>()`. What kind of reference can you assign it to? Only a `List<?>`. That means you won't be able to put any references in (other than null), and you won't be able to get any references out except as `Object`. In other words, this generic is slightly less useful than the raw types that generics were meant to replace.

When you see a `List<?>` or `List<? extends Foo>`, chances are very good that somebody created it as an un-wildcarded type, and then cast it to the wildcarded type. For instance:

```
List<? extends Number> getSomeNumbers() {
    List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2L);
    numbers.add(3.14);
    return numbers; // implicit casting to List<? extends Number>
}
```

In this example, if `numbers` had been typed as `List<? extends Number>`, none of the `add` lines would have compiled, so it wouldn't have been useful. If we had constructed the object as `new ArrayList<? extends Number>()`, we'd have no choice but to reference it in that useless, wildcarded form.

Similarly, if you had created a `new ArrayList<? super Number>()`, then the adds would have worked, but you'd be guaranteeing that nobody could ever retrieve values except as `Object`. You could have done the same by just creating (and referencing) a `new ArrayList<Object>()`.

So then, why is `new ArrayList<Set<?>>()` allowed? Because it *is* useful; we can add elements to the list, as well as retrieve them. As we create each set, we'll create it with no wildcard so that we can add to it, and then we'll cast it down and add it to the list.

```
List<Set<?>> getSomeSets() {
    List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<?>>();
    Set<Number> set = new HashSet<Number>();
    set.add(1);
    set.add(2L);
    set.add(3.14);
    Set<?> wildcardSet = set; // allowed, though not actually needed
    list.add(wildcardSet);
    list.add(set); // don't need to go through intermediate wildcardSet
    return list;
}
```